# What would be a realworld example of an application having multiple Cache Manager in Ehcache?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

According to [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/code-samples), an application can have multiple CacheManagers. Since multiple cache's can be maintained in a single CacheManager, what benefit are we getting by having multiple CacheManagers? Is distributec cache has any relation with multiple CacheManagers? I tried googling it and found none. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Caches distributed over different machines perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here are some practical examples:

1. You're building an app using two different libraries, both of which use EhCache for different purposes. To avoid having them interfering with each other, you probably want them using different `CacheManager`s (for example, if lib A does `cacheManager.removeCache("foo")` and lib B uses a cache with the same name, you probably won't end up happy).
2. You want caches with different scopes - say, one that lives over the scope of a single request, another with session scope, a third with application scope, etc.
3. Last, but not least, an important question when one thinks a singleton seems like a good idea - why *should* the number of instances be limited to exactly one?